# Multiple JBoss/WildFly deployment descriptors in a single WAR

Tags: java, deployment, jboss, wildfly, deployment-descriptor

Our application runs unchanged on JBoss 6 EAP and 7 Community. Now we want to add support for WildFly 9 and we found out that we need to change various JBoss deployment descriptors (jboss-deployment-structure.xml, jboss-scanning.xml, jboss-web.xml) that are packaged in the application WAR to make the app work on WildFly 9. Unfortunately these changes seem to break backward compatibility of our app with older JBoss releases.

Is there any way to have multiple JBoss deployment descriptor versions in a single WAR archive so that each JBoss version picks the highest version that it can support?

Our goal is to have a single application WAR that works **unchanged** on JBoss 6.x EAP, JBoss 7.x Community as well as WildFly 8.x and 9.x.

Comment: Just line of note, jboss-scanning.xml is not used in AS7+/EAP6+ anymore and has no effect on your deployment at all.

Comment: What are the differences between the descriptors for AS7/EAP6 and the ones for WildFly? This will help us understand what could be done to unify the config

Comment: In the end it turned out to be a problem with the jboss-deployment-structure.xml descriptor. In it we had a required line that read <module-alias name="ourapp.war"/>. While this caused no issues in JBoss 6/7, it caused an issue in WildFly 9, because WF9 expects the module alias name to start with 'deployment.'. Adding this prefix fixed the issue and we can continue using a single set of deployment descriptors for all JBoss/WF releases.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is currently no way to do this with a single jboss-deployment-structure.xml file.

My teams have taken one of the following approaches to solving this:

1. Create a custom module that gets installed in each app server and have the jboss-deployment-structure file only reference this custom module.
2. have a separate maven profile for each app server you wish to deploy on. This isn't ideal because it produces different war files for your different servers. This is neccessary for projects where other files need to change as well such as beans.xml or web.xml.